# How to create a new object in Rails with a predefined property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that has a bunch of pages, each page has many convos. On each page there's a link to create a new convo on that page. This is the code for that link:

<%= link_to 'New Convo', new_convo_path(:page=>@page) %>

However, on the next page, "convo/new" the page property is empty. What am I missing?

EDIT here are my new and create functions for convos

```
   def new
    @convo = Convo.new(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @convo }
    end
  end



  # POST /convos
  # POST /convos.xml
  def create
    @convo = Convo.new(params[:convo])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @convo.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@convo, :notice => 'Convo was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @convo, :status => :created, :location => @convo }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @convo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You mean the page parameter isn't accessible through `params[:page]`?

Comment: i mean it should. i'll post my new and create functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the page ... try to set a before filter ...

```
before_filter :find_page

private
  def find_page
    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
  end
```

Then you build using nested resources

```
def new
  @convo = @page.convos.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @convo }
  end
end

def create
  @convo = @page.convos.build(params[:convo])
  .....
end
```

Comment: so before_filter goes in the convos_controller class and def find_page in the convos model?

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `before_filter' for #<PagesController  Do you know what might be causing that?

Comment: hmm, before_filter is defined in ActionController .... Application controller inherits  ActionController and your pages controller should inherit the application controller .... make sure your controller has the following definition class PagesController < ApplicationController

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are missing a ":page=>"

```
def new
  @convo = Convo.new(:page=>params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @convo }
  end
end
```